# Styles and DataTemplates: FindAncestor-like search including Self

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource, findancestor

I have a style containing binds expression of the form

```
{Binding Path, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyType}}}
```

However, sometimes the DataContext in which this style operates is actually of type MyType. In this case, FindAncestor doesn't do what I want: it starts its search from the parent.

Is there any {Binding ...} incantation that checks the type of the current datacontext before continuing up the element hierarchy? I have other solutions specific to my project, but FindAncestor is *so close*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelativeSource` bindings do not look for DataContexts, they search the visual tree for UI elements. The `AncestorType` should be a control.

To perform a `RelativeSource` binding on the same control you can use `RelativeSource Self`